# How to reload a video everytime web page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I wanted a function that could change my background everytime I reload the page, but it ain't working.

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
  var source = document.getElementById('video-source');
  var videos = [
  "videos/vid1.mp4",
  "videos/vid2.mp4",
  "videos/vid3.mp4"
];

  var randomVideo = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

source.setAttribute('src', randomVideo);
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE it is not affecting the web page, the video is still the same after reloading.

Comment: @HunainAhmed . **Your video playing same means ** - At certain `Timestamp`  like: 02:33 , 03: 22 **OR** Same Video Playing again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it seems that the code run and update your video source in every page-refresh, but because the array is too small (although your random method gives a chance to each element) it might always pick one the same one
You can try to use `arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) % arr.length]` to pick random element from small arrays. If it doesn't work, add the line `debugger;` to the begining of your js and debug it step-by-step, that's how you can make sure that your code runs again whenever the page reloads.
If you want to make sure that the selected video will be different from previous one, you can use the code below to choose video url:

```js
function selectRandomElement(arr) { //assume arr contains at least two elements
    var res;
    while((res = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) % arr.length]) == localStorage['lastVideo']);

    localStorage['lastVideo'] = res;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Your code also is not working. what should I write in the place of arr.length ?

Comment: The meaning of "arr" is Array, you should send your array to the function I wrote in order to pick a random video, e.g. var randomVideo = selectRandomElement(videos);